# How to decompose an object and make it the following structure with help of reduce function

Tags: javascript

how to create with help of reduce method next structure

```
let events = {
    '2019-12-29': ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7'],
    '2019-12-30': ['name4', 'name8', 'name9'],
    '2019-12-31': ['name2', 'name6'],
}
```

====>how to make this structure

```
let events = [
    {
        date:  '2019-12-29'
        event: 'name1'
    },
    {
        date:  '2019-12-31'
        event: 'name2'
    },
    {
        date:  '2019-12-29'
        event: 'name3'
    },
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use reduce

```
    Object.keys(events).reduce((acum, cur) => {
  events[cur].forEach((n) => {
    acum.push({ date: cur, event: n });
  });
  return acum;
}, []);
```

You can then `sort` the above array by the name field
I wanted to mention that `reduce` normally used to convert an array to an object which is not similar to your use case!
You need to convert the object to an array that's why using `Object.keys`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.entries()` and then `reduce()` function:

```js
let events = { "2019-12-29": ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7'], "2019-12-30": ['name4', 'name8', 'name9'], "2019-12-31": ['name2', 'name6']};

let output = Object.entries(events).reduce((arr, ent) =>
    [...arr, ...ent[1].map(n => ({date: ent[0], event: n}))],
    []);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get all the entries of the object and [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) by iterating over all the dates for an event, and pushing them to the accumulator array.

```js
let events = {
    '2019-12-29': ['name1', 'name3', 'name5', 'name7'],
    '2019-12-30': ['name4', 'name8', 'name9'],
    '2019-12-31': ['name2', 'name6'],
}
const res = Object.entries(events)
   .reduce((acc,[date,names])=>(names.forEach(event=>acc.push({date,event})),acc),[]);
console.log(res);
```